# AFNetworking https request not working

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I try connect to https server, but I get error -1012(NSErrorFailingURLKey). If I try connect to http then all is good. But I should connect to https. What does it can be? I tried connect via AFNetworking v1.0 and v2.0. I used AFHTTPRequestOperation, AFHTTPRequestOperationManager, AFHTTPClient and other.
P.S. When I try connect to https via firebug, all is good. I mean, server works good.

Comment: can you show some code please ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with `#define _AFNETWORKING_ALLOW_INVALID_SSL_CERTIFICATES_ 1` to allow invalid or self signed certificates.

By default, they are not allowed, see `AFURLConnectionOperation.h`

Answer (score 4):

The security policy in AFNetworking states that `allowInvalidCertificates` defaults to `NO`. You need to set it to `YES`.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES; // not recommended for production
```

More details:
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#security-policy

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a newer version of the AFNetworking library and #define is not working.

The issue was fixed with setting the property **allowsInvalidSSLCertificate** to **YES** on the client itself:

```
httpClient.allowsInvalidSSLCertificate = YES;
```

Comment: @ghazi_jaffary it's an instance of AFHTTPClient

Comment: Ok i have been using 2.0 version which have no AFHTTPClient class so i was wondering. Thanks

Comment: What "newer version". Please state. Is HTTPClient even available with AFNetworking v2?

Answer (score 0):

It works on me:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager* manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[manager POST: urlString parameters:bodyDict
     success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject){

     return;
     }
     failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error){

      failBlock(error);
     }
 ];
```